# Opencart: CSS (based on route maintenance)

Tags: php, css, opencart

This is my first question here. I'm using Opencart for my webshop. For the looks i'm styling the CSS of my pages e.g. account_login.css. But i also want to do the Maintenance page. I already made the common_maintenance.css file. But when i'm testing my site isn't displaying correct. It is just showing http://www.mywebsite.com instead of http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?route=common/maintenance. Please can somebody help me with this?

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonMaintenance extends Controller {
 public function index() {
     if ($this->config->get('config_maintenance')) {            $route = '';
                    if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
            $part = explode('/', $this->request->get['route']);

            if (isset($part[0])) {
                $route .= $part[0];
            }                       }
                    // Show site if logged in as admin          $this->load->library('user');
                    $this->user = new User($this->registry);
            if (($route != 'payment') && !$this->user->isLogged()) {
            return $this->forward('common/maintenance/info');           }                       
     }
 }
        public function info() {
     $this->load->language('common/maintenance');

     $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

     $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

     $this->document->breadcrumbs = array();

     $this->document->breadcrumbs[] = array(
         'text'      => $this->language->get('text_maintenance'),           'href'      => $this->url->link('common/maintenance'),
         'separator' => false
     ); 

     $this->data['message'] = $this->language->get('text_message');
            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . 
 '/template/common/maintenance.tpl')) {
         $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/maintenance.tpl';
     } else {
         $this->template = 'default/template/common/maintenance.tpl';        }
                $this->children = array(            'common/footer',            'common/header'         );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
 } } ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any URL Rewriting configured?

Comment: How are you changing the css exactly? This needs more information

Comment: The pages load there own CSS with this code  in catalog/controller/common/header.php, Right after the line protected function index() { on a new line :$route = empty($this->request->get['route']) ? 'common/home' : $this->request->get['route'];
    $css_file = str_replace('/', '_', $route) . '.css';

    if(file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/' . $css_file)) {
        $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template'). '/stylesheet/' . $css_file);
    } @JayGilford

Comment: I've indented your code with for spaces, rather than ">", so it will display with highlighting. Also, the code is a mess if you look at indendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the hideous formatting, and added the call to the ->addStyle($css). If the code does not work yet, please check if I got the path to the CSS right (where it says $css = 'blahblah' );

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonMaintenance extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        if ($this->config->get('config_maintenance')) {
            $route = '';
            if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
                $part = explode('/', $this->request->get['route']);
                if (isset($part[0])) {
                    $route .= $part[0];
                }
            }

            // Show site if logged in as admin
            // $this->load->library('user');
            $this->user = new User($this->registry);
            if (($route != 'payment') && !$this->user->isLogged()) {
                return $this->forward('common/maintenance/info');
            }
        }
    }

    public function info() {
        $this->load->language('common/maintenance');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
        $css = 'catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/common_maintenance.css';
        $this->document->addStyle($css);
        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $this->document->breadcrumbs = array();

        $this->document->breadcrumbs[] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_maintenance'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/maintenance'),
            'separator' => false
        );

        $this->data['message'] = $this->language->get('text_message');

        $maintenance = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/maintenance.tpl';

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $maintenance ) ) {
            $this->template = $maintenance;
        }

        else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/common/maintenance.tpl';         }
            $this->children = array(
                'common/footer',
                'common/header'
            );

            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks Barry but it did not work. i've got the following message:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/theshopspot.nl/public_html/theshopspot/catalog/controller/common/maintenance.php on line 56. When deleting this line i got the following error: Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in /home/theshopspot.nl/public_html/theshopspot/catalog/controller/common/maintenance.php on line 15.  I have no idea what to do. My css file is named common_maintenance.css by the way. Any advise? @BerryLangerak

Comment: @BarryLangerak It's solved! I took you code:   $css = 'catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/common_maintenance.css';
        $this->document->addStyle($css); and placed it in the original php file. That did the trick! Thank u very much!

Comment: @coen1234 It's the standard to accept an answer, once it has solved your problem. And you're welcome :)

Comment: At to moment i'm also stuck with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664777/opencart-checkout-facebook-connect. Do you think you can help me we that? @BerryLangerak

Comment: @coen1234 No, sorry, I'm not an OpenCart expert, really.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using the route, which the maintenance mode doesn't change when it's in maintenance mode. What you need to do is specifically add that stylesheet in the maintenance controller using the `$this->document->addStyle()` method

Comment: Do i have to put that line in de maintenance.php file? Can you please specify cause i'm a starter. Thanks

Comment: Yes you need to add it in the maintenance.php controller file, within the index() method towards the top of it

Comment: I've tried the above but i'm doing it very wrong i think nothing work. Here's my stylesheet without the $this->document->addStyle() line. Can you tell me where to put is and do i need to include common_maintenance somewhere?

Comment: <?php
class ControllerCommonMaintenance extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        if ($this->config->get('config_maintenance')) {
   $route = '';
   
   if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
    $part = explode('/', $this->request->get['route']);
    
    if (isset($part[0])) {
     $route .= $part[0];
    }   
   }
   
   // Show site if logged in as admin
   $this->load->library('user');
   
   $this->user = new User($this->registry);
 
   if (($route != 'payment') && !$this->user->isLogged()) {
    return $this->forward('common/maintenance/info');
   }      
        }

Comment: Please edit your original post with the code and formatting. It's incomprehensible like that